# Python Flask mod-wsgi Custom Headers not in Request

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I've a simple Python Flask application, which is being served by Apache via mod_wsgi.

The part of my application which works perfectly on my localhost, but does not work through mod_wsgi is the accessing of custom request headers.

When I request a certain web page, I pass it a header called `auth_user`. On my localhost, I am able to access this header as: `request.headers["auth_user"]`, which works great. However when served through Apache and mod_wsgi, this custom header does not exist! Printing all `request.headers` shows that the standard `Content-Type`, `Cache-Control` headers are sent, but not the `auth_user` header which i've been sending to my localhost with no problem.

Tcpdump shows that the server `is` receiving the header, but it is not available in my `request.headers`.

Does anyone have any idea why this header is not being made available within the app?

Answer (score 12):

Well this one took me many hours...

Turns out that only alphanumeric characters or '-' are allowed.

Any headers not conforming these will be ignored.

http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/release-notes/version-4.3.0.html <- Bug fixes, point 2.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your Apache configuration has the [WSGIPassAuthorization directive](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration-directives/WSGIPassAuthorization.html) set to 'On' so your headers get past Apache + WSGI and to your Flask app.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the claim prefix to something without `_` like

```
OIDCClaimPrefix OIDC-CLAIM-
```